# Post docs in online/distance learning mode

Tags: postdocs, computer-science, academic-life

For a Mathematics scholar, who is interested in Cryptography, AI and Computer Science related fields, are there any post-doc researches available to be done by online/distance learning mode?

If there's a way to do such a one please kindly advise

Comment: I also have such questions in mind.

Comment: This is considered a shopping  question on this site, thus off-topic.

Comment: I'm confused - if funding isn't an issue, what exactly is meant by a postdoc, especially remotely?  Mathematics researchers (including postdocs) work fairly independently from their advisors - why can't you just collaborate with someone (the way mathematicians do)?  And if no one will collaborate with you - no one would be willing to hire you for a postdoc either, because a postdoc is just a junior scholar you want to collaborate with to the extent you're willing to help negotiate funding for them.

Comment: Sorry @AlexanderWoo I've edited the question now. I mean are there such opportunities advertised where we can apply? I searched but I can't find such, but I thought maybe they are present in inside university notices or something. If so, then it's helpful for me to find if any of you will mention a few such universities. Else, is there a way to start a post doc even without applying? I mean is this a way: talk with a lecturer and if he agrees to collaborate, I can get enrolled with him as a post doc?

Comment: The language you use suggests that you think of a postdoc as a student. That is wrong. It is a job, a junior job, but a job none the less. So you need to think of this as a job search process, not as finding an educational institution that will take you: What do you want from the institution hiring you, and what do you have to offer. Somehow you need to bring those two together so it is beneficial for both sides.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot @MaartenBuis. How can I figure out whether there are opportunities to do it in an online mode? What is the method to search and apply?

Comment: The same as in any other form of job search.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo, in my country post doctoral experience carries separate marks in faculty recruitment. So there is another aspect besides salary in post-doctoral position. Some PhD holder might do a permanent job in lower position (e.g. high school teacher etc) but he/she aspire to be in university/college and in which case post-doctoral experience might play a positive factor. Though I am not sure any such distance mode post-dctoral is possible.

Comment: @learner: the idea that faculty recruitment would be done by a system of marks is so foreign to me that I must suppose I understand absolutely nothing about your system and what you need.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo, it is indeed in practice. For example, in India, several faculty recruitment clearly mention one needs at least 3 years experience in post doctoral. Besides that post doctoral experience is counted in "experience section" for marks. I am sure this is somewhat is true in other countries as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are in luck because most work in those fields does not need specialised equipment and can be done remotely.

Whether there exist positions that allow you to do it vary on some factors:

1. The degree of remote work. Postdocs in math/CS are very often (nearly always?) allowed to work from home or any other location; they are rarely expected to be in the office, but some in-person presence may be necessary. The answer to your questions thus depends on whether you are looking for exclusively remote positions or you are okay with infrequent visits to the office (visiting once a month is not unheard of, for instance).
2. Your role. Most postdocs in math/CS, at least in Europe, are nearly 100% research focused, which helps the case for remote work. If the position expects you to teach, TA, or supervise students, you are more likely to be expected in-person.
3. The group culture. Smaller groups or those that have a stronger focus on internal collaboration or social actives might be less likely to hire someone who's mostly remote, whereas groups with mostly independent members may be more inclined.

Overall, the answer depends on how remote you need the position to be, but it is possible that some positions exist that satisfy your criteria. Note, however, that no position will be marked as such: you need to reach out to the potential supervisors and ask whether they would be okay with a remote postdoc.